# Ubuntu 14.04.2 freezes before log-in screen

Tags: 14.04, boot, drivers, nvidia

Recently, I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 14.04.2, and made a few installations. After making these installations, Ubuntu would not load. It would freeze at the splash screen, displaying the Ubuntu logo with the dots, but never progressing to the log-in screen.

So, I did another fresh installation of Ubuntu, and slowly made the installations incrementally until Ubuntu failed to load again. Here are those installations:

1) Ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get` upgrade to upgrade all existing packages.

2) Downloaded Nvidia proprietary driver (`nvidia-346`) for my graphics card (GTX 880M) and selected to use it in `Additional Drivers`.

3) Installed a number of packages: `apt-get install cmake build-essential libopencv-dev libbost-all-dev freeglut3-dev libglu-dev libglew-dev libcheese7 libcheese-gtk23 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libcogl15 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-0 xserver-xorg-input-all`.

I rebooted after steps 1 and 2, and Ubuntu loaded up fine both times. However, after step 3, it fails. But this time, rather than freezing at the splash screen, it goes as far as making the short noise that normally sounds just as the log-in screen displays, but then just goes to a black screen with a small dash in the top-left. I cannot type anything to this screen.

My intuition is that this might be something to do with the Nvidia driver, because it seems like a display problem. But then why would Ubuntu load successfully after step 2?

I could now go ahead and reinstall Ubuntu again, then reboot after installing each of these packages, but this seems a little exhaustive and not really addressing the issue in the right way...

I'm also puzzled as to why it froze at the Ubuntu logo screen the first time, and now it is freezing at a black screen...

Any help? Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: this is how to install nvidia manually http://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-from-the-run-file/423619#423619

Answer (score 0):

First, 
between " rescoue mode" or alternate your runlevel:
[What is the difference between single user mode, recovery mode from GRUB, and booting with Ubuntu install disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234636/what-is-the-difference-between-single-user-mode-recovery-mode-from-grub-and-bo)

After remove all drivers NVidia:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*
```

After install aptitude e synaptic

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude synaptic
```

**aptitude:** best binário installer the like-debian ever, verify high complex contexto, sample: conflict between repositories

**synaptic:** manager package interface Graphical.

Second:

download and install driver correct:

```
wget -c https:us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/346.59/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.59.run
```

after install:

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.59.run
```

verify your Ubuntu is 32 or 64 bits, The links of the above are 32 bits.

After install backage NVIDIA, install manager NVIDIA:

```
sudo aptitude install nvidia-settings
```

font: http://goo.gl/qhqtnD