# Is there a way to tell if Ubuntu is running in recovery mode via terminal?

Tags: command-line, ssh, recovery-mode

I'm logged in via ssh(which I thought should not even be in recovery mode?) since my raspberry pi doesn't have monitor or keyboard. I've been having to remount the root directory as `rw` and there are lots of admin commands that are acting weird.
I could technically connect my pi to hardware and see what happens during Grub but I was just wondering if it's possible to do it just via terminal.

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu boots into Recovery automatically. Unless you specifically booted it into Recovery, I doubt you're in it.

Comment: That was my initial thought too but lot of strange things is happening in my pi so I was wondering if I could check it just to confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell if Ubuntu is running in recovery mode via terminal?

From the webpage [How to check a current runlevel of your Linux system](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-check-a-current-runlevel-of-your-linux-system):

> Debian distribution has it runlevel 2-5 dedicated to full multi-user with graphical managers and console login whereas Redhat/Fedora has two separate runlevels for each mode. To check the runlevel of you system you can use runlevel command with no arguments:
>
> ```
> runlevel
> ```

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/234657/271) says that the default runlevel in Ubuntu is `2`, but for me it is `5`. Anyway, recovery mode is a different number.

> I've been having to remount the root directory as `rw`

*Probably* your system remounted it to `ro` because there were I/O errors on the device. You should [schedule a `fsck`](https://askubuntu.com/a/476314/271) and maybe consider buying a new SD card.

Comment: Okay, I see that my runlevel is `5` as well. And this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/234657/87340) helped me a bit understanding the runlevel of recovery mode. And you maybe right on the corrupt SD card.

Comment: @shriek Great. Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it satisfies you.

Comment: Ahh sorry. Was trying to go look for another SD card. Regarding the `fsck` that didn't seem to help either.